# Use ST_DWithin to query pairs of geometry points within 400 miles in a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, geometry, cursor, gis, postgis

I have a table called h2combines in Postgres that has two points-geometry fields: geom1 and geom2, and some other fields. I want to select all records that geom1 and gemo2 are with 400 miles. I tried this:

```
SELECT * from h2combines WHERE ST_DWithin(geom1, geom2, 643738);
```

However, it returned all rows. Seems I misunderstand something here.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your EPSG(SRID) for your geoms? If 4326 you will have to transform to geography as Jim Jones show you or transform to SRID=3857 with e.g. st_transform(geom1, 3857).

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO.

To get the distance in meters/miles you have to cast your geometries to `geography`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM h2combines 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom1::geography, geom2::geography, 643737.6);
```

Keep in mind that calculations using `GEOMETRY` and `GEOGRAPHY` are made differently, and so are their results. `GEOGRAPHY` calculates the coordinates over an spherical surface (which can be much slower than `GEOMETRY`) and uses meters as unit of measurement, while `GEOMETRY` uses a planar projection and uses the SRS unit.